# check if the values in an array are the same as the values as the values of a selectbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Is it possible to check if there is a match between values inside and array and values of a select box? I need to check if the value of the select box is in the array so if it is I can change its class to something else. noobie here

**EDIT**

I have been working on recreating my question so it can be more understandable.
On this fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jbn9dopu/)  you can see that I am dynamically creating new selectboxes using a button! In each of the buttons, the selection is being disabled but only for that box. What I want to do is that if one value is selected all of the others will be deactivated, in all the other boxes. 
I tried insert in an array all the values of the selected values and then compare them in order to disable them but I only managed to do it in each box. ALSO the data from the selectboxes come from a database! 
 any tips?

//this supposed to disable the selected options

```
$('#sig_3').on('change', '.c_service_c', function() {
  var value = $('#type').val();
  var selected_array = [];

  $('.c_service_c option:selected').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") { //$(this).val()!="" --> remove the check on 'Please Select' option
      selected_array.push($(this).val()); //save selected values so that they can be disabled later
    }
  });

  console.log('print: ' + selected_array);
  //reset all values to 'Y' before changing selected to 'N'
  $('.c_service_c option').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") { //$(this).val()!="" --> remove the check on 'Please Select' option
      $('.c_service_c option').addClass('Y'); //resetting all options to 'Y'
    }
  });

  if (selected_array.indexOf($('.c_service_c').val()) > -1) {
    $('.c_service_c option:selected').removeClass('Y');
    $('.c_service_c option:selected').addClass('N');
    console.log('it prints here too');
  }

  //disable all selected values in options array
  if (selected_array.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1) {
    $('.c_service_c option:selected').removeClass('Y');
    $('.c_service_c option:selected').addClass('N');
    console.log('it prints');
  }

  //disable all selected values
  $('.c_service_c option').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") { //$(this).val()!="" --> remove the check on 'Please Select' option
      if ($(this).hasClass('N')) {
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
        $(this).removeClass('N');
      } else {
        $(this).addClass('Y');
        $(this).attr("disabled", false);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you looking to retrieve the selected value from the select box, or all values?

Comment: im looking to cross reference them.. to see which ones are in the array in order to disable them

Comment: Please show a sample of your code in order that we can provide a relevant answer in order to help you and in order that we can illustrate that answer with relevant code to show how it works. Please read both the "[mcve]" and "[ask]" guidelines

Comment: @DavidThomas i asked if its possible to do such thing, i never said i wrote a code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want for each `options` to check if the `option` exists in an array, and based on to disable it or not, you just need to loop over the `options` using `.each()` function and do your check.

This is how should be your code:

```
$("#dropdown option").each(function() {
  if (arr.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1) {
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```js
var arr = ["apple", "tomato", "peach", "pineapple"];


$("#dropdown option").each(function() {
  if (arr.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1) {
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="apple">Apples</option>
  <option value="orange">Oranges</option>
  <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
  <option value="lemon">Lemon</option>
</select>
```

**Edit:**

I **[updated your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/jbn9dopu/1/)** so it's working now, your problem was that you declared `selected_array` in a local scope for `$().each()` it needs to be declared as global.

Comment: what i want to do is that it does exist to disable it so if i create any new select boxes it won't be available

Comment: but that disables them only in that box not in others

Comment: @noel293 What others? Can you please edit your question with the relevant situation?

Comment: @noel293 Ok, I will check it, but can you post your HTMl as well?

Comment: @chdsk great example mate but is it possible to make them available again if they are unselected?

Comment: But how would you deselect it if it's disabled?

Comment: @chdsk if I select something else on the box.. e.g. if i select on box1 the value 1 then no other boxes will have it enabled but if i deselect it and select something else then the other boxes will have it as enabled

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using jQuery as well, and assuming I understand correctly what you are asking, try the following:

```js
//available values
var arr = ["apple", "tomato", "peach", "pineapple"];

$("#select-dropdown").on("change", function() {
  //store value on local variable
  var value = $(this).val();

  //search the value inside the array, return -1 if can't find
  var index = arr.indexOf(value);

  if (index != -1) {
    //found value in array, add the new class!
    $(this).addClass("my-new-class");
  } else {
    //didnt found anything, remove class
    $(this).removeClass("my-new-class");
  }
});
```

```css
.my-new-class{
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-dropdown">
  <option value="apple">Apples</option>
  <option value="orange">Oranges</option>
  <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
</select>
```

Comment: this does not do exactly what i want to do but i got the logic behind it! check my edited question for more details please